# HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am working on AWS Athena to run query it was working just fine now the same query give me this error :

> HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR

This query ran against the "mytable" database, unless qualified by the query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out The problem was : I added a column with the type of `date` in glue but in s3 it is stored as `string`. I Hope this may help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was a column of type `double` that was stored as `int64` in the parquet file.